# How to create a formula for my inventory list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In an Excel worksheet, I have a cost column (B) and price column (C). Is there a formula that will give me the percentage markup in column D?

ex. B-C=?, B/?=, then multiply by 100 for percent

An example of the required calculation is:

- Price (100) - Cost (85) = 15
- 85/15= 0.17= 17% markup

Answer (score 1):

```
=(C1-B1)/B1
```

Then set the cell format as %

Comment: Thank you! I only need it from row 27 to 1858. I don't remember how to have the formula apply to those rows without doing each individual cell. Would you mind helping please?

Comment: Just copy it and paste it in the required range, the rows should adjust automatically

Comment: I feel ridiculous asking that. Got it! Thanks!! Do you know if a column can 'pull out'/highlight any of the prices that are over or under 30%?

Comment: I mean over 40% and under 30% of that new column

Comment: =IF(D1>.4,"Over",IF(D1<.3,"Under","")